# Imask.js set currency symbol to the and of number by appending changeable double zero to the end of price

Tags: javascript, input, masking, price, maskedinput

How to do input masking something like this by appending doube zero by default to the end of price using js library [imask.js](https://imask.js.org/) or with plain javascript : **3.380.321,00 $**

```js
var currencyMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('price'),
  {
    mask: '$num',
    blocks: {
      num: {
        mask: Number,
        thousandsSeparator: '.'
      }
    }
  });

var currencyMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('price2'),
  {
    mask: 'num$',
    blocks: {
      num: {
        mask: Number,
        thousandsSeparator: '.'
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<input type="text" id="price" value="2700300.21">
<hr>
<p>Needed masking: 3.380.321,00 $</p>
<input type="text" id="price2">
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```js
var currencyMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('price'),
  {
    mask: [
        { mask: '' },
        {
            mask: 'num $',
            lazy: false,
            blocks: {
                num: {
                    mask: Number,
                    scale: 2,
                    thousandsSeparator: '.',
                    padFractionalZeros: true,
                    radix: ',',
                    mapToRadix: ['.'],
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<input type="text" id="price" value="3380321.00">
```